# Can I straighten and make uniform the edges and lines of an icon?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have some icon images which have these wavy edges from the source image. I have increased the size and resolution of the icons. I'm wondering if there's a way to make them straight and uniform with Photoshop. Either one at a time, or all of them together on one image. I'm fairly new to photoshop and couldn't find the answer to this question elsewhere. Using the warp tool didn't seem to do the trick for me, given the waviness of the lines.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I think it would be simpler to just redraw the icon with the Pen Tool.  Also Photoshop is not the right kind of software for making icons anyway. Use a vector image editor like Illustrator or Inkscape.  It's not a complex design, would only take a couple of minutes.

Comment: Yup.. most would *redraw*. Garbage in <> Garbage out. It would take much, much. much.much more effort to "clean that up" than it does to just redraw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in an easy way, no.

If you're assuming there's a button in Photoshop that you can click and *boom* the lines as straight, nope, there isn't a button for that.

Icons are generally constructed line by line. If this particular icon is distorted, that's probably what the author intended, or the file is broken somehow.

If you don't know how to redraw it, and not interested in learning how to do it, there are many icon websites where you can download identical symbols with straight lines. Many times these come in collections, meaning you get a large set of icons in the same style.

If you do attempt to rebuild it, safely assume Illustrator is the better tool for this. Using Photoshop is not impossible, but tricky. Either way you need to learn to use the app first.

Comment: Thanks man. I have a sheet of about 100 icons that are all similar in style and context and have these wonky lines, which is why I was hoping there was a way to easily straighten out all the edges in one go, rather than redraw all the icons. But I will just redraw the ones I need, as I need them. I don't have illustrator, but I'll look into it, thank you.

Comment: See this https://thenounproject.com/search/icons/?iconspage=1&q=box

Answer (score 0):

as Billy Kerr said in the comments above you are using the wrong tool to achieve it.

But if you want to make it happen in Photoshop then have you tried tracing the image using pen tool ?

[image: Sample Video]

Comment: Cheers, I'll give this a shot. I have a sheet of about 100 icons that are all similar in style and context and have these wonky lines, which is why I was hoping there was a way to easily straighten out all the edges in one go, rather than redraw the icons. But I will just trace redraw the ones I need, as I need them. Thank you.